# Using scaling instead of breakpoints on desktop

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, responsive

I'm building a responsive website which has 3 different dseigns: one for mobile, one for tablet and one for desktop.
For each resolution I use a breakpoint, but on desktop there are many screen sizes and resolutions so I have to use many breakpoints inside the desktop breakpoint.

Is it possible to set the page to scale itself so it looks the same on every desktop resolution (of course the page would be smaller on smaller screens), and use the breakpoints only for mobile and tablet?

Thank's,
Daniel.

Comment: your question is not very specific... are you talking of a full-width website? can you show some (only the imporant) code?

Comment: There is no code yet. I'm still planning... And yes it is a full width website (1920).

Comment: okay.. so theoretically that is possible... but actually i don't think that it would be a good idea... it would be a big hassle and generate a lot of problems... what about compatibility of older browsers? different aspect ratios? and and and?

Comment: You're thinking all wrong. What you have is not a "responsive website" - it's a hackjob. What you do is you create the desktop website first (because desktop is the least capable browser when it comes to @media-queries), and then you add breakpoints (using `em`, not `px`) for when the screen gets too small to hold everything. The goal is not to get everything looking the same, it's to get the page working at any resolution. "phones" and "tablets" aren't one size fits all - there is a big range from an iPhone 4 to a fullHD or retina screen.

Comment: I know that. I build the mobile first, then tablet, and only then desktop. Of course I make compatibility fixes on mobile and tablets, but on desktop the variety of screens is too wide... So I want the page to scale itself.

Answer (score 0):

When you are at your desktop breakpoint you could use percentage widths so that the website scales if a user changes the size of the screen.

e.g:

```
.main-container {
  width: 80%
}
```

Comment: You could use percentage widths for images, fonts on the other hand need different treatment, i agree.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. One way to do this is to set your page by default to have a fluid layout and use % for main column (and sidebars if any), and then to set breakpoints with media queries for your mobile break points and control the layout differently for each. For your default "desktop layout" you can set a max-width to restrain the fluid layout. Personally I would take a mobile first approach and style for mobile by default and then change for desktop at a specific breakpoint.